# Keras Sequential NN cannot learn with perfectly explanatory variables - why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am experiencing some troubles with training and predicting a time series using neural network in Python.

The dataset I am using is very simple: A target column consisting of zeros and ones. There is only one explanatory variable and it is the target values shifted. I.e if at time t the target is to predict 1 then there will be a 1 in the explanatory column at time t-1. Thus I would expect this case to be easy to predict. To use data equal to mine one could do the following:

```
# Load packages:
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import random
from keras.layers import GRU
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create dataset
a = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
b = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})

# Split into X and y data
class_X, class_y = dataset.values[:, :-1], dataset.values[:, -1]

# Last column in the dataframe should be the one we want to predict
def spitIntoTrainAndTest1(dataFrame):
values = dataFrame.values
# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = values[:, :-1], values[:, -1]
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))

return train_X, train_y

# Split classification into test and training data
X_clas2, y_clas2 = spitIntoTrainAndTest1(dataset)

# Used in RNN
X_clas_RNN = np.squeeze(X_clas2, axis=1)
y_clas_RNN = np.expand_dims(y_clas2, axis=1)

# Used in GRU
lengthOfDataset = len(X_clas2)
train_X_clas2 = np.squeeze(X_clas2, axis=1)
X_clas_GRU = np.reshape(train_X_clas2, (lengthOfDataset,1,1))
y_clas_GRU = y_clas_RNN
```

The next part is about fitting a model to the data:

```
# Parameters in the fitting
numberOfEpochs = 100
batchSize = 50
printFit = 1# 1 = true
randomSeedNumber = 164
validationSplitRatio = 0.33

# ORDINARY RNN MODEL:

# create model
random.seed(randomSeedNumber)
model_RNN = Sequential()
model_RNN.add(Dense(32, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model_RNN.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_RNN.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model_RNN.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
RNN_history = model_RNN.fit(X_clas_RNN, y_clas_RNN, 
validation_split=validationSplitRatio, epochs=numberOfEpochs, 
batch_size=batchSize, verbose=1)

# WEIGHTED GRU MODEL:

model_GRU_weight = Sequential()
model_GRU_weight.add(GRU(1, input_shape=(1,1)))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model_GRU_weight.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model_GRU_weight.fit(train_X_clas3, train_y_class, epochs=100, batch_size=500, class_weight = 'auto')
GRU_weight_history = model_GRU_weight.fit(X_clas_GRU, y_clas_GRU, validation_split=validationSplitRatio, 
                                      epochs=numberOfEpochs, batch_size=batchSize, verbose = printFit, 
                                      class_weight = 'auto', shuffle=False)
```

Finally I want to evaluate the results/predictions:

```
# Combine the predictions on the test dataset

# Predicitons made
firstValObs = round(validationSplitRatio*len(X_clas_RNN))+1
valSet2 = X_clas_RNN[firstValObs:,:]
valSet3 = X_clas_GRU[firstValObs:,:]
actuals = pd.DataFrame(y_clas_RNN[firstValObs:,:])
predictions_RNN = np.round(model_RNN.predict(valSet2))
predictions_GRU_weight = np.round(model_GRU_weight.predict(valSet3))

timeSequence = np.r_[1:(len(predictions_GRU_weight)+1)]
firstValObs = round(validationSplitRatio*len(X_clas_RNN))+1

# Plot predictions
numberOfRows = 3
numberOfCols = 1
minY=-0.1
maxY = 1.1

plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(numberOfRows, numberOfCols, 1)
plt.plot(timeSequence, actuals)
plt.ylim((minY,maxY))
plt.title('Actuals')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(numberOfRows, numberOfCols, 2)
plt.plot(timeSequence, predictions_RNN)
plt.ylim((minY,maxY))
plt.title('RNN predictions')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(numberOfRows, numberOfCols, 3)
plt.plot(timeSequence, predictions_GRU_weight)
plt.ylim((minY,maxY))
plt.title('GRU weighted predictions')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

The obtained plot looks like this:

[image]

At the moment the RNN is making correct predictions. If instead I change the code to:

```
# create model
random.seed(randomSeedNumber)
model_RNN = Sequential()
model_RNN.add(Dense(32, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model_RNN.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model_RNN.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model_RNN.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
RNN_history = model_RNN.fit(X_clas_RNN, y_clas_RNN, 
validation_split=validationSplitRatio, epochs=numberOfEpochs, 
batch_size=batchSize, verbose=1)
```

The result will be like:

[image]

There are different things I find odd.

I am a bit surprised because it seems to me that it must have a sufficient number of neurons in each layer to make this simple prediction (shifting the series one period). Can this really be the case that the number of neurons in the RNN in the second code snippet aren't sufficient?

I do not understand why the weighted GRU cannot make better predictions. If the answer to the first question is that a higher number of neurons improve performance then I think there should be enough here. Also I find it hard to accept that it overfits as it should be pretty simple to just shift it one period. Nevertheless it always predicts 1 - do you have any explanations for this?

Furthermore I would like to know if there are any rules of thumb for the value of the input parameters (epochs, batch size, number of layers, number of neurons in each layer). My actually considered dataset has the same length as this (around 500) but 5 input variables (X) instead of just one column as in the above described example.

Please, do not hesitate to add a comment if you have any idea of something I am doing wrong or should consider.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your model is significantly more complicated than needed for the task. If there is a perfectly explanatory variable, then you would only need a single neuron and just that feature to learn the relationship.

Comment: Have you tried using a simpler model - perhaps not deep learning? I'm thinking something like a random forest would work (although that might overfit). It's usually best to start with the simplest model possible (so in the case of classification a logistic regression) and then work your way up to a more complex model.

Comment: You answered as I was writing below. 
Thanks for your advice. I will take a further look at it tomorrow.
I have never used a random forest for a time series - how do you do this? Do you add them as explanatory variables (X-values) to predict a target value (y)?

This example was constructed to illustrate a problem I faced with a more complex data set (where it might not just be one previously observation but maybe ten earlier observations that should be considered) - should I in this case make ten x-values for each y-value to predict?
Hope it is clear, what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks for your answer, caseWestern.

I did try to make a few changes:

```
# ORDINARY RNN MODEL:

# create model
random.seed(randomSeedNumber)
model_RNN = Sequential()
model_RNN.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model_RNN.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model_RNN.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model_RNN.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
RNN_history = model_RNN.fit(X_clas_RNN, y_clas_RNN, validation_split=validationSplitRatio, epochs=numberOfEpochs, batch_size=batchSize, verbose=1)

# WEIGHTED GRU MODEL:

model_GRU_weight = Sequential()
model_GRU_weight.add(GRU(1, input_shape=(1,1)))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model_GRU_weight.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model_GRU_weight.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model_GRU_weight.fit(train_X_clas3, train_y_class, epochs=100, batch_size=500, class_weight = 'auto')
GRU_weight_history = model_GRU_weight.fit(X_clas_GRU, y_clas_GRU, validation_split=validationSplitRatio, 
                                          epochs=numberOfEpochs, batch_size=batchSize, verbose = printFit, 
                                          class_weight = 'auto', shuffle=False)
```

The result I obtain still look like this:
[image]

Regarding the over complicated model: Because there is no noise in the data (it is totally clean as it is just shifted) I cannot see what it should over overfit on..? Additionally, I agree a simple model would be enough, but I would expect a more flexible/complicated model to be able to capture it too, because there is no noise to "disturb it". Please feel free to give your thoughts on it.

As mentioned above my results did not improve - did I do, what you ment?